# Meaning of "slice"

Tags: meaning

What is the meaning of *slices* here?

> Switching barcodes is a pretty common crime and hard to catch if you're smart about it. Bringing your own barcodes to the store is pretty creative though.
>
> Now many barcodes/price tags have the **slices** in them, so they come apart if a swap is attempted. Especially at places pofolks frequent.

Comment: *"Pofolks"*?!? Does it mean *police people*? I couldn't find the expression anywhere.

Comment: It's a slang term for poor folks I think.

Comment: Voting to close as not a real question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*Slices* here refers to a pattern of cuts through the sticker that make it difficult to remove said sticker in one piece.  This makes swapping stickers almost impossible as it is easy to tell that the sticker being swapped in is not the original.

In my experience, the slices are in an x pattern like the one pictured below, although there are several variations including chevrons (<<<).

[image]

Many more (awesome and vintage) high-resolution examples can be viewed [here](http://www.flickriver.com/photos/neatocoolville/sets/72157621940407287/).